Namecheap https forwarding issue with Wix website
I have a domain from Namecheap (let's call it forwarddomain.com) and want it to forward to a specific page on my Wix website (e.g., wixwebsite.com/forwardsite).
The issue I'm facing is that https://forwarddomain.com doesn't work correctly. I can only forward forwarddomain.com (without HTTPS) to wixwebsite.com/forwardsite, but when I try https://forwarddomain.com it keeps loading forever and shows "This site can't be reached). Not having HTTPS creates issues for me when people try to open the HTTPS page or when embedding in apps like WhatsApp, etc.
I've reached out to Namecheap support, but I wasn't able to resolve the issue. It seems others have encountered similar problems with forwarding HTTPS domains with HTTPS, but I have not found the Wix website case. Ideally, I'd like to fix this without causing significant downtime, as the forwarding domain is already live and has been shared.
Anybody can help?
